# How can we share settings values across Liferay themes in same war

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

We have a one theme application with 2 themes packages in it.We need to share settings from one theme to the other.

```
<theme id="visual" name="visual-theme" >
        <settings>
            <setting key="service-unavailable" configurable="true" type="checkbox" value="false"></setting>
        </settings>
    </theme>

    <theme id="visual-home" name="visual-theme-home" >
        <settings>
            <setting key="h1-title-value" configurable="true" type="textarea" value="" ></setting>
            <setting key="service-unavailable" configurable="true" type="checkbox" value="false"></setting>
            <setting key="service-unavailable-message" configurable="true" type="textarea" value="Unavailable service"></setting>
        </settings>
    </theme>
```

We need `service-unavailable-message` setting to be available to `visual-theme` as default value, so that when set from `visual-theme-home`,it should be available to the other theme as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings are per theme, not per web application, thus the settings for some area with theme A will have no effect on anything with theme A. You'll have to use another technique for achieving this.

When you use theme settings, you can set these values either per site or per page. In the later case, this would introduce yet another ambiguity.

So one option you have is

```
<theme id="visual" name="visual-theme" >
  <settings>
    <setting key="service-unavailable" configurable="true" type="checkbox" value="false"></setting>
    <setting key="service-unavailable-message" configurable="true" type="textarea" value="Unavailable service"></setting>
  </settings>
</theme>

<theme id="visual-home" name="visual-theme-home" >
  <settings>
    <setting key="h1-title-value" configurable="true" type="textarea" value="" ></setting>
    <setting key="service-unavailable" configurable="true" type="checkbox" value="false"></setting>
    <setting key="service-unavailable-message" configurable="true" type="textarea" value="Unavailable service"></setting>
  </settings>
</theme>
```

...and duplicate the message whereever you need.

Another option is to move `service-unavailable-message` to another place (as a more general configuration value, or looked up from some service. Just not as a theme setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!Apart from this,don't we have anything where in,the 'service-unavailable-message' is available as well as configurable from both theme settings,and reflects in both themes as well?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of Liferay are you using. If using Liferay 7.0 by any chance, look into [themelets](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/themelets), you can put the code reused in themes into a themelet and access it from your themes.